# Map in Cordova is wrongly sized

Tags: google-maps, size

I have created an Cordova based smartphone app where I would like to load a Google map to show the users routes. The problem is that the map is loaded in a completely wrong size than I told it to (height: 100%).

[image]

The map is now shown, like in the picture above. When I watch the map however in the web browser with "cordova serve" the map is loading with the correct size. Does anybody know how I can fix this issue? My CSS looks like this:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 900px) {
#map-canvas-meine-Fahrten{
    height: 100%;
    width: 90%;
    padding-top: 5%;
    padding-right: 5%;
    padding-bottom: 5%;
    padding-left: 5%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to that element css to make it full screen

```
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
```

**Updated Answer**

Media query is not used properly for mobile screen.

Comment: Thanks, I added it to the CSS but somehow it didnt change anything.

Comment: Since I am loading the Map in a div can the css settings of this div somehow influence the map?

Comment: Ok, Would you check for its parent element, and try to set the height to 100%

Comment: My map-canvas div (where it is loading the map) is in 2 other divs, i set the height of these divs to 100% but it didnt change anything as well :(

Comment: Umm, maybe media query 'min-width' is not proper for mobile device. 900px is good for normal computer screen or Hi-res mobile device. Try to test without media query first. Then, if it works, try to change 'min-width' to lower than your device screen width in portrait mode.

Comment: Thanks you very mutch! The problem is fixed now. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: What do you mean with accepted answere? :D I think turning down the min-width solved the problem (: